# Making variable negative with memory modification

Tags: python, memory, ctypes

I have been working on a simple program that modifies memory values with the `id()` function. It works for the most part, but something weird happens when I try to assign the negative of the positive value (ex. 4 to -4). Instead I get a value of -253 if I start with the value 3. How do I fix this and why is it happening?

Code:

```
import ctypes
import sys

def mutate(obj, new_obj):
    if sys.getsizeof(obj) != sys.getsizeof(new_obj):
        raise ValueError('objects must have same size')

    mem = (ctypes.c_byte * sys.getsizeof(obj)).from_address(id(obj))
    new_mem = (ctypes.c_byte * sys.getsizeof(new_obj)).from_address(id(new_obj))

    for i in range(len(mem)):
        mem[i] = new_mem[i]
        
x = 3
y = 5

print(x)
mutate(x, y)
print(x)
print()


x = 4
y = -4
print(x)
mutate(x, y)
print(x)
```

Output:

```
3
5

4
-252

(Exit code -1073740940)
```

Comment: It looks as if you would also copy the reference count. This will lead to crashes/leaks.

Comment: Integers are immutable and there is an integer pool for values -5… 255, changing them could lead to very strange results…

Comment: What @ead said.  This could (and does, on my system) crash Python.  I had better luck with 999 and -999 since that number isn't cached, and it also worked as you intended, but mutating a "immutable integer object" is going to break things, especially if it is a commonly used number.

Comment: What's the purpose of this? Looks like an *XY Problem*.

Comment: @CristiFati The purpose is just to learn something about memory modification with a high level language and the x, y variables could be replaced with anything.